# Python: sending request to the protobuf server

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, rpc, proto

Can somebody help me?

I have a .proto file.

How to send and print request to the socket server from the client?
How to make response to the client?

protofile:

```
option optimize_for = SPEED;
option java_package = "org.epicsquad.protofile.proto";

package protofile.proto;

enum CommandTypeEnum {

COMMAND_one = 0;
COMMAND_two = 1;  
COMMAND_three = 2;

}

enum ResultTypeEnum {

RESULT_ONE = 0;
RESULT_TWO = 1;

message Result {

required uint32 result_one = 1;
optional string result_two = 2;

}

message Request {

optional string req1 = 1;
optional string req2 = 2;  

}

message Response {

required string resp1 = 1;
required string resp2 = 2;

}
```

server:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../main')
import protobuf.socketrpc.server as server
server = server.SocketRpcServer(8090)
print 'Serving on port 8090'
server.run()
```

client:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../main')
import protofile_pb2
from protobuf.socketrpc import RpcService
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
hostname = 'localhost'
port = 8090
request = protofile_pb2.Request()
```

I have a HelloWorld example but there sending request going through the SERVICE. But there are not service messages in my .protofile.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

add `option py_generic_services = true;` this line your .proto file.
if you don't do this, protoc wont generate the stubs you need for rpc